# Tail implementation using a dynamic queue library

Tags: performance, c, programming-challenge, memory-management

As per [K & R exercise 5-13](http://www.eng.uerj.br/%7Efariasol/disciplinas/LABPROG/C_language/Kernighan_and_Ritchie/solved-exercises/solved-exercises.html/krx513.html)

> Write the program tail, which prints the last n lines of its input. By default, n is 10, say, but it can be changed by an optional argument, so that

> ```
> tail -n
> ```

> prints the last n lines. The program should behave rationally no matter how unreasonable the input or the value of n. Write the program so it makes the best use of available storage; lines should be stored as in the sorting program of Section 5.6, not in a two-dimensional array of fixed size.

I've written my own version of tail in C. It uses a newer version of a library for a dynamic queue that I also wrote and submitted here before (I've made a lot of changes to it since then). I'd like to get some feedback on how my code performs, both memory wise and speed wise, and how I might improve this in the future. I've compared its performance to the GNU implementation of tail and found that for small files my program uses *less* memory but for larger files it uses a fair bit more (although I did find that GNU tail leaks memory - 96 bytes according to Valgrind) and I was hoping I could get some insight as to how it does this better.

### tail.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dqueue.h>

#define MAX_LEN 256
#define MAX_LINES 32
#define DEFAULT_TAIL 10

int getlinep(char *s, int lim);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *line;
    char *temp;
    int tail_len = DEFAULT_TAIL;
    queue_t * queue = NULL;
    int elements;
    int len;

    if(!(queue = queue_init(sizeof(char *)))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d: Could not initialise queue!\n", MEM_ERROR);
        return MEM_ERROR;
    }

    if(argc >= 2) {
        if(atoi(*(++argv))) {
            tail_len = -atoi(*argv);
            if(tail_len <= 0 || tail_len > MAX_LEN)
                tail_len = DEFAULT_TAIL;
        }
    }

    for(elements = 0; elements < tail_len; elements++) {
        if(!(line = malloc(MAX_LEN))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory allocation failure!\n");
            return MEM_ERROR;
        }

        if(!getlinep(line, MAX_LEN)) {
            free(line);

            if(elements == 0) {
                queue_destroy(&queue);
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }

            break;
        }

        queue_push(&line, queue);
    }

    if(elements == tail_len) {
        if(!(temp = malloc(MAX_LEN))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory allocation failure!\n");
            return MEM_ERROR;
        }
        for(;;) {
            if(!(len = getlinep(temp, MAX_LEN))) {
                free(temp);
                break;
            }

            queue_pop(&line, queue);
            memcpy(line, temp, len + 1);
            queue_push(&line, queue);
        }
    }

    while(elements-- > 0) {
        queue_pop(&line, queue);
        printf("%s", line);
        free(line);
    }

    queue_destroy(&queue);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int getlinep(char *s, int lim)
{
    int i;
    
    for(i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (*s = getchar()) != EOF && *s != '\n'; i++, s++)
        ;

    if(*s == '\n') {
        s++;
        i++;
    }
    
    *s = '\0';
    
    return i;
}
```

### dqueue.h

```
#ifndef DQUEUE_H
#define DQUEUE_H

#include <stdlib.h>                                                     /* Needed for size_t */

#define QUEUE_OK 0
#define MEM_ERROR -1                                                    /* Memory allocation error */
#define SIZE_ERROR -2                                                   /* Queue dimension error */
#define INDEX_ERROR -3                                                  /* No data at given index */

#define BLOCK_SIZE 1024

typedef struct queue_element_t
{
    void * data;                                                        /* Contains the data stored at this node */
    void * next;                                                        /* Contains the pointer to the next element, or NULL if it's the tail node */
} queue_element_t;

typedef struct
{
    queue_element_t *   head;                                           /* Pointer to the head of the queue */
    queue_element_t *   tail;                                           /* Pointer to the tail of the queue */
    size_t              size;                                           /* The number of elements in the queue */
    size_t              element_width;                                  /* The size of each element in the queue */
    size_t              tail_pos;                                       /* The byte offset of the data being pushed into the queue (i.e. in the tail block) */
    size_t              head_pos;                                       /* The byte offset of the data being popped out of the queue (i.e. in the head block) */
    int                 status;
} queue_t;

queue_t *   queue_init(size_t element_size);                            /* Initialise the queue data structure */
void        queue_pop(void * const element, queue_t * queue);           /* Pop an element from the front of the queue, deals with cleanup when the head node is empty */
int         queue_push(const void * const element, queue_t * queue);    /* Push an element to the back of the queue, creates a new block when tail node is full */
int         queue_debug(const queue_t * const queue);                   /* Print information about the queue, returns the queue status if a valid queue pointer is given  */
void        queue_destroy(queue_t * queue);                         /* Destroy the queue data structure and any associated nodes */

#endif
```

### dqueue.c

```
/* 
 * Filename:    dqueue.c
 * Date:        17/02/18
 * Licence:     GNU GPL V3
 *
 * Library for a lightweight, generic, and dynamically allocated queue
 *
 * Return/exit codes:
 *  QUEUE_OK        - No error
 *  SIZE_ERROR      - Queue size error (invalid block size or number of elements)
 *  MEM_ERROR       - Memory allocation error
 *  INDEX_ERROR     - Couldn't pop data from the queue
 *
 * All functions returning pointers will return NULL on memory allocation faliure, else they will specify an error in queue->status for the user to handle
 *
 * Todo:
 *  - Add secure versions of queue_destroy() and queue_pop() to overwrite memory blocks that are no longer in use
 * 
 */

#include <dqueue.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

queue_t * queue_init(size_t element_width)
{
    queue_t * queue;

    if(!(queue = malloc(sizeof(queue_t))))
        return NULL;

    if(BLOCK_SIZE % element_width != 0 || (queue->element_width = element_width) <= 0) {
        queue->status = SIZE_ERROR;
        return queue;
    }

    queue->tail_pos = 0;
    queue->head_pos = 0;
    queue->tail     = NULL;
    queue->head     = NULL;
    queue->size     = 0;
    queue->status   = QUEUE_OK;

    return queue;
}

void queue_destroy(queue_t * queue)
{
    queue_element_t * temp;

    if(queue == NULL)
        return;

    while(queue->head) {
        free(queue->head->data);
        temp = queue->head->next;
        free(queue->head);
        queue->head = temp;
    }
    
    queue->size             = 0;
    queue->status           = 0;
    queue->element_width    = 0;
    queue->tail_pos         = 0;
    queue->head_pos         = 0;
    queue->tail             = NULL;

    free(queue);
}

int queue_push(const void * const element, queue_t * queue)
{
    queue_element_t * new_element;

    if(queue->tail_pos == 0) {
        if(!(new_element = malloc(sizeof(queue_element_t)))) {
            queue->status = MEM_ERROR;
            return queue->status;
        }

        if(!(new_element->data = malloc(BLOCK_SIZE))) {
            free(new_element);
            queue->status = MEM_ERROR;
            return queue->status;
        }

        if(queue->head == NULL)
            queue->head = new_element;
        else
            queue->tail->next = new_element;

        queue->tail = new_element;
        queue->tail->next = NULL;
        queue->size++;
    }

    memcpy(queue->tail->data + queue->tail_pos, element, queue->element_width); 

    queue->tail_pos += queue->element_width;

    if(queue->tail_pos >= BLOCK_SIZE)
        queue->tail_pos = 0;

    return queue->status;
}

void queue_pop(void * const element, queue_t * queue)
{
    queue_element_t * temp;

    if(queue->head == NULL || ((queue->head == queue->tail) && (queue->head_pos == queue->tail_pos))) {
        if(queue->tail_pos == 0) { /* Catch an error related to reseting the tail position and incrementing a block after a block has been filled */
            queue->tail_pos = BLOCK_SIZE;
        } else {
            queue->status = INDEX_ERROR;
            return;
        }
    }

    memcpy(element, queue->head->data + queue->head_pos, queue->element_width);

    queue->head_pos += queue->element_width;

    if(queue->head_pos >= BLOCK_SIZE) {
        free(queue->head->data);
        temp = queue->head;
        queue->head = queue->head->next;
        free(temp);

        queue->head_pos = 0;
        queue->size--;
    }
}

int queue_debug(const queue_t * const queue)
{
    if(queue == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Invalid queue pointer!\n");
        return MEM_ERROR;
    }

    if(queue->status == QUEUE_OK) {
        printf("Queue is %d blocks long with an element width of %d bytes with each block containing %d elements\nQueue head is at %p and the current element is %p\n", (int)queue->size, (int)queue->element_width, BLOCK_SIZE / (int)queue->element_width, (void *)queue->head, (void *)queue->tail);
    } else if(queue->status == MEM_ERROR) {
        printf("Memory error in queue!\n");
    } else if(queue->status == SIZE_ERROR) {
        printf("Size error in queue!\n");
    } else if(queue->status == INDEX_ERROR) {
        printf("Index error in queue!\n");
    }

    return queue->status;
}
```

Comment: Curious: In `queue_debug()`, why code `printf("...  %d ...\n", (int)queue->size, ...);` versus `printf("...  %zu ...\n", queue->size, ...);`?  I am confident you are aware of `"%zu"` and `size_t` as you rightly  coded `"%p"` with a `void*` casted pointer.

Comment: @chux Actually no, until I looked it up just now I wasn't particularly aware of length field modifiers for format strings, thanks for the tip

Comment: queue_destroy(queue); instead of queue_destroy(&queue);?

Comment: you rely on GCC void * pointer arthmatics see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113301/how-void-pointer-arithmetic-is-happening-in-gcc/13113325#13113325)  . code only work is element_width = 1

Comment: @wooooooooosh I know about the void pointer arithmetic thing, I couldn't come up with a better way to do it and keep the queue generic, any ideas of how to improve on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most misleading thing in your code was this line in `queue_element_t` typedef:

```
void * data;
```

You would think data is a pointer to data, but rather it is a pointer to an array of pointer to data. So it should really be:

```
void * * buffer;
```

Or even better let's make "pointer to data" a new type.

```
typedef void* Data_Ptr;

typedef struct 
{
    Data_Ptr * buffer; 
    void * next;
} queue_element_t;
```

There are several things we need to change:

- In queue_push we can use pointer assignment instead of memcpy. Replace:

  ```
  memcpy (queue->tail->data + queue->tail_pos, element, queue->element_width);
  queue->tail_pos += queue->element_width;
  ```

  with

  `queue->tail->buffer [queue->tail_pos] = element;
  queue->tail_pos ++;`

You can even combine those two lines if you want.

- You should change the signiture of queue_pop to `Data_Ptr queue_pop (queue_t * queue)` and return element or NULL; Change where you call the function to `line = queue_pop (queue);`
- Same with queue_pop

  ```
  element = queue->head->buffer [queue->head_pos];
  queue->head_pos ++;
  ```
- queue_push should become `int queue_push (Data_Ptr element, queue_t * queue)` element don't need to be const because we are passing in by value. Change where you call the function to `queue_push (line, queue);`

Once we make this change some optimization opportunities become clear.

- We don't need to know element_width anymore because it is sizeof(Data_Ptr). Delete anything to do with `element_width`.
- Not sure about the exact requirement of the exercise, but since we know the maximum size of the queue, we don't even need to use a linked list. we can just dynamically allocate an array of Data_Ptr. Refer to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-set-1introduction-and-array-implementation/) for implementation of array-based queue.
- You don't need to have a separate malloc for temp line for when you have n_element in the array already, just allocate n_element+1 lines in the previous loop, then just pop 1 line and use that as temp.

**Other error:**

- You did not check if `queue *` passed in queue_push and queue_pop is not NULL, result in UB.
- `void queue_pop(void * const element, queue_t * queue);`

  should really be

  `void queue_pop(void ** element, queue_t * queue);`

  in your implementation.
- `queue_destroy(&queue);`

  signature of `queue_destory` is

  `void queue_destroy(queue_t * queue);`

  but you passed `queue**` it should really be

  `queue_destroy(&queue);`

  there are 2 occurance of this.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you are allocating `BLOCK_SIZE` bytes for each item in the queue, whereas they can be at most `MAX_LEN` bytes long, am I reading this correctly? And MAX_LEN is 256, where BLOCK_SIZE is 1024, so you are only using at most 25% of the allocated memory.

Another thing is that malloc() has a minimum block size, which is [32 bytes for dlmalloc](http://prog21.dadgum.com/179.html). Assuming you are on a 64 bit platform, your `queue_element_t` is `2*sizeof(void *) = 16` bytes. Therefore you are also loosing 16 bytes per element. You can avoid this by allocating the `queue_element_t` along with its buffer in one go:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE (256 - sizeof(void *))
typedef struct {
  void *next;
  char data[BLOCK_SIZE];
} queue_element_t;
```

Then queue_element_t will be nicely allocated to a 256 byte bloc and no memory will be wasted in overhead.

Comment: Your first point is incorrect, each block in the queue can hold 1024 / element_width (in this case 4) elements. This is accounted for with the head_position and tail_position variables which keep track of the current position within the head and tail blocks.

Comment: I do like your second point though, there is no good reason to dynamically allocate the data segment of the queue_element_t and the queue_element_t itself separately, so doing this both together to reduce overheads is a good idea